# Retrieve a JSON feed using jquery getjson?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I have been playing with this code for way too long for no solution.

The url that it points to contains this (json object):

```
{ "description": "Input 1", "type": "no", "enabled": true, "alarm": false }

$(document).ready(function () {
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'http://192.168.1.2/alarm.cgi',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                // begin accessing JSON data here
                console.log(description);
            }
        });
    });
```

Shouldn't this return "Input 1" since that is the description?

Comment: nope, it will get you the whole `json`, access it with `console.log(data.description)`

Answer (score 2):

The value of `data` is the whole object, you need to access the `description` property, so it should be `console.log(data.description);`.

Answer (score 2):

You get `Shadowed variable name` in your example, just don't do it.
Give different name to callback parameter, `response` for instance:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'http://192.168.1.2/alarm.cgi',
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            // begin accessing JSON data here
            console.log(response.description);
        }
    });
});
```

In this example you'll get `response = '{ "description": "Input 1", "type": "no", "enabled": true, "alarm": false }'` and you can read description property inside `response` object: `response.description`

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, the function to be called if the request succeeds returns you one object that's named `response`, which should have `{ "description": "Input 1", "type": "no", "enabled": true, "alarm": false }` as content.
To return one object property, you need to call the object name and, after that, his attribute.
To return the `description`, you have two ways:

1. Calling with `.`: `response.description`; or
2. Calling with `[]`: `response["description"]`.

```js
var response = { "description": "Input 1", "type": "no", "enabled": true, "alarm": false };

console.log('With ".": ' + response.description);
console.log('With "[]": ' + response["description"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

$(document).ready(function () {
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'http://192.168.1.2/alarm.cgi',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                // begin accessing JSON data here
                console.log(data[0].description);
            }
        });
    });
```